# MathOverflow's Facebook page

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/MathOverflow/135885609778430) for MathOverflow is currently pulled from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathOverflow). The [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/MathOverflow) has no avatar and only 90 follows. The most active is the [Google+ account](https://plus.google.com/104052965640286446927/posts), which posted about moderator elections 5 months ago.

It would be nice to see MO have more of a social media presence.

Would you be interested in converting the FB page into an official page, and having it be managed by the MO community? Being a social-media manager (or content curator) for MathOverflow could be an elected position, like being a moderator on the site.

This could also tie into the thread on [how to emphasize MathOverflow's best content](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/948/how-to-emphasize-mathoverflows-best-content?rq=1): post it on social media, and target influencers to share it (e.g., Terry Tao).

Comment: What are the advantages of MO having more of a social media presence?

Comment: It seems like a bit of a waste of time, and likely to attract the wrong kind of users.

Comment: It seems that a social-media tag would suffice. No need for the specific tags. (In fact, I'm not sure that the social media tag is needed either.)

Comment: I will add my voice to Asaf Karagila's suggestion of removing the tags 'facebook', 'twitter', and 'google+'.

Comment: somewhat related http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1599/mathoverflow-community-relations/

Comment: Personally I am not (yet) convinced of the idea, but to discuss it seems interesting so I upvoted.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Perhaps the already existing ([meta-tag:site-promotion]) tag would be better here? (Instead of facebook, twitter, google+.)

Comment: This older discussion seems related (to some extent): http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1253/does-mathoverflow-really-want-the-publicist-badge

Comment: @Martin: Spot on, methinks.

Comment: I find this one an entirely reasonable question; are the downvotes being used to mean "I disagree", rather than "it's a bad question"?

Answer (score 5):

As a comparison, see the Facebook page for the [American Mathematical Monthly](https://www.facebook.com/AmerMathMonthly).

When it was decreed from on high that there should be such a page, most of the old fogeys (who make things run at the MAA) were opposed.  But you can see how it looks today after running for a year or so.  Of course, they have far more people and budget for such things than MO does.

Comment: The first thing I see when I click on the link you provide is a request to register at Facebook, like always with Facebook links. I don't like this -- in my opinion, reading a webpage should be possible without getting requests to register, to subscribe or to buy something.

Comment: A better example or model might be the AMS page on Google+, which currently has over 136,000 followers: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AmsOrg

Comment: @Stefan: So, are you saying: because of the registration request, we should just leave the page as the boilerplate, and not do anything with it?

Comment: @StefanKohl Facebook page would be for Facebook users. Not everyone is or wants to be on Facebook. But I don't see how it implies that there should be not MO community on FB.